# Automated interaction within ssh session

Tags: python, paramiko, pexpect

I need to collect some output via ssh from different devices but there are two caveats:

1. The devices are interactively asking for credentials so login can't be easily automated
2. The output is paged, so it is required to press "Enter" a number of times to get to the end of it

I've tried using paramiko_expect, I can manage the authentication but then I can't figure out how to loop in a while-like style.

```
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction
try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(addresses[0], username = username, password = password, look_for_keys = False, allow_agent = False)
    output = ""
    with SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout = 10, display = False) as interact:
        interact.expect(['User:.*'])
        interact.send(username)
        interact.expect(['Password:.*'])
        interact.send(password)
        interact.expect(['.*>'])
        interact.send('get output')
        interact.expect(['.*>','.*More or (q)uit.*'])
        keepOnLooping = True
        while keepOnLooping == True:
            if interact.last_match == '.*More or (q)uit.*':
                interact.send(interact.send(' '))
                interact.expect(['.*>','.*More or (q)uit.*'])
                keepOnLooping = True
            elif interact.last_match == '.*>':
                interact.send(interact.send(' '))
                keepOnLooping = False
        output = interact.current_output
```

I've tried with pexpect (pxssh) but I'm failing at the authentication phase.

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = input('hostname: ')
    username = input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.expect('User:.*')
    s.sendline(username)
    s.expect('Password:.*')
    s.sendline(password)
```

Any suggestions on how to automate the mentioned proceedures?

Comment: i never used `paramiko_expect` but for `pexpect` my suggestion is don't use `pxssh`.

Comment: I must run this on Windows (unfortunately) where `pexpect.spawn` is not available. That's why I was looking for a way to embed the ssh part.